# selecting data stored in a table form mysql and displaying into new table

Tags: php, database, html, phpmyadmin, connection

I don't understand how to get this done using PHP. Please have a look at the tables   below and guide me.

The card has $ 8 credit

The tab  A is already populated  with data and stored in PHPmyadmin.   The product that is going  be purchased by clicking the button ADD

**TAB A**

```
products    | cost
product A     $ 2    -ADD button
product B   | $ 3    -ADD button
product C   | $ 4    -ADD button
```

By clicking ADD the tab B displays  the products selected

**TAB B**

```
products    | cost
product A   | $ 2
product B   | $ 3
--------------------
tota    | $ 5    -PAY button
-------------
```

by clicking PAY sumtotal amount.  Below show the total credit from the card

new credit:

```
credit  | $3
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: how display results like 'TAB B'